# Refreshing a file in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, file-io

I'm writing a JSP application which writes a text file to be downloaded by the user. The only problem is that the tomcat filesystem isn't refreshed so when the user clicks the download link a previous version of the text file is loaded. How can I make it reload the text file?

edit: Here's the code i'm using:

```
java.io.FileWriter outputFile = new java.io.FileWriter("C:\\Users\\simon\\workspace\\anotherTest\\WebContent\\file.txt");
java.io.BufferedWriter outfile = new java.io.BufferedWriter(outputFile);
outfile.write(text);
outfile.close();
```

Below this is the download link

```
<a href=file.txt>download</a>
```

edit2: I've been trying different code snippets from around the internet but still to no avail. I assumed that there must be a lot of people who are using JSP to generate dynamic files to be downloaded. Can anyone point me towards an example?

Comment: what operating system is this using?

Comment: I'm using windows 7 with tomcat using default settings

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that you call [`close()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#close%28%29) or *at least* [`flush()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#flush%28%29) (only when you'd like to keep the pointer open for some reason) on the `OutputStream` after writing to the file. This way the changes will be reflected in the disk file system.